# Merge without header columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, merge

I am using a table detection module to detect the table and extract the content from it.
I am using a pandas data frame to order the data in the table structure.

Scenario - 1.

I need to merge column 4(Amount) with column 5(empty header).

[image]

the expected output like this,

[image]

Scenario - 2

In this the price, amount value extracted in other columns, I need to move back to its original column.

[image]

the expected result is,
[image]

NOTE: All values are dynamic, it will change for other types of images.

Comment: There is necessary columns names `0,1,2,3 ?` not `Article no., 'Description', ...` ?

Comment: I am facing this issue for more images. For other images, the column number will be different. For those images, I am facing dataframe issue.

Comment: Answer was edited, can you check?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get the expected result. It will the same as the original format.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is combine all rows without first with convert to strings and extract column by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html):

```
df.loc[df.index[1:], 5] = df.loc[df.index[1:], 5].astype(str) + df.pop(4).iloc[1:]
df.loc[df.index[1:], 8] = df.loc[df.index[1:], 8].astype(str) + df.pop(7).iloc[1:]
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print (df)
             0                   1         2         3       4      5  \
0  Article no.         Description   Content  Quantity   Price    VAT   
1        18001  Thai Mineral water  28X0,33L       400  6,160E  O 0/0   

          6  
0     Total  
1  2464,00E
```

Or if possible empty string in first row use:

```
df[5] = df[5].astype(str) + df.pop(4)
df[8] = df[8].astype(str) + df.pop(7)
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print (df)
             0                   1         2         3       4      5  \
0  Article no.         Description   Content  Quantity   Price    VAT   
1        18001  Thai Mineral water  28X0,33L       400  6,160E  O 0/0   

          6  
0     Total  
1  2464,00E
```

Last if necessary convert first row to columns names:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  Article no.         Description   Content Quantity   Price    VAT     Total
0       18001  Thai Mineral water  28X0,33L      400  6,160E  O 0/0  2464,00E
```

More general solution use `groupby` with `sum` with created duplicated columns names:

```
#convert missing values to empty string
df.iloc[0] = df.iloc[0].fillna('')

#convert columnc names to series
s =  df.columns.to_series()

#if empty string in first row then replace column name by next one
df.columns = s.where(df.iloc[0].ne('')).bfill()
#for join use sum
df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()
#set default columns names
df.columns = np.arange(len(df.columns))
print (df)
             0                   1         2         3       4      5  \
0  Article no.         Description   Content  Quantity   Price    VAT   
1        18001  Thai Mineral water  28X0,33L       400  E6,160  O 0/0   

          6  
0     Total  
1  E2464,00
```

Comment: The currency symbol and header name are dynamic. It will change for other types of images.

Comment: Yes, but the result does not change.

Comment: @BHARATH -  It not working for any data? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Your 3rd answer works for the first scenario but in the second scenario, it does not work. Other answers do not work for both scenarios.

Comment: @BHARATH - What is second scenario?

Comment: Hi, Please check my updated question. All the values are changing.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
import numpy as np
import unicodedata

#locating the currencies
currencies = ['DOLLAR SIGN','EURO SIGN','POUND SIGN','RUPEE SIGN']
#list of a few currencies https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm

pos = []
bag = []
for val in df.values: #val is ndarray type

    s  = np.array_split(val,len(df.columns))
    bag.append(s)

for cur in currencies:

        symbol = np.where(bag == np.array([unicodedata.lookup(cur)]))   

        if symbol[0] != np.array([]):
            pos.append(symbol)
```

1st are rows, 2nd are columns

```
for p in pos:

    for r,c in zip(p[0],p[1]):
        ncol = c+1
        bag[r][ncol] = bag[r][c]+bag[r][ncol].astype(str)  # replace the money in good place        

#convert bag in dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(bag)

to_drop = []
for cur in currencies:  

    d = unicodedata.lookup(cur)

    for col in df2.columns:

        if d in df2[col].tolist():
            if col not in to_drop:
                to_drop.append(col)

#drop undesired columns
df2 = df2.drop(columns=to_drop)
```

This is the output for your first excel print

```
    0                     1  ...        6           8
0  [Article no.]         [Description]  ...    [VAT]     [Total]
1        [18001]  [Thai Mineral water]  ...  [O °/o]  [€2464,00]

[2 rows x 7 columns]
```

dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Article no.','Description','Content','Quantity','','Price','VAT','','Total'],
                [18001,'Thai Mineral water','28X0,33L','400','€','6,160','O °/o','€','2464,00']]
                ,columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

And the output for your second excel print

```
     0       1           2        3           5
0  [Description]      []  [Quantity]  [Price]          []
1      [Gourmet]  [AXML]       [781]   [9,00]  [$7029,00]
2        [Taste]  [BXML]       [398]   [8,90]  [$3542,20]
```

dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Description','','Quantity','Price','Amount/GBP',''],
                ['Gourmet','AXML','781','9,00','$','7029,00'],
                ['Taste','BXML','398','8,90','$','3542,20']]
                ,columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Comment: The currency symbol and header name are dynamic. It will change for other types of images.

Comment: With this euro = np.where(s == np.array(['€']))   you will find euros positions. And you will get headers name with this: header = list(df.loc[0])

Comment: Sir sorry for confusing you..., for my extraction the data should be changed. So the currency value change from euro to some other countries currency type. So it should not be a fixed one. Same as table header names. All the fields are dynamic.

Comment: Hi, Please check my updated question. All the values are changing.

Comment: @BHARATH check out. I've changed the code based on your comments.

Comment: About Scenario 2, you are expecting the code to guess where the currencies symbol are and where they belong. You should try to control some of the "dynamics"  issues while importing or exporting the file.

Comment: Yes, I need a dynamic solution for both scenarios.